# how to write inside the <p> tag using selenium webdriver in python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

My html code is :

```
<p contenteditable="true" ></p>
```

I want to write code inside the p tag using selenium webdriver.

i tried

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url_link)

write = browser.find_element_by_tag_name("p['contenteditable':'True'")
write.text('hello')
```

but it gives error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: 
An invalid or illegal selector was specified
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to locator like xpath  to get the element.

Here is an xpath example

```
write = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//p[@conteneditable=‘true’]")
```